# Using Intl.DisplayNames() to convert country code from ISO-3 to ISO-2

Tags: javascript, data-conversion, country-codes

I'd like to convert country codes from ISO-3 to ISO-2 via an official method to prevent any mistakes or depreciation. Is it possible with `Intl.DisplayNames()` ?